# QIIME 1.9: ImportError: cannot import name subsample_counts

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, qiime

Every time I try to run any qiime script I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/assign_taxonomy.py", line 14, in <module>
    from qiime.util import (parse_command_line_parameters, get_options_lookup,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qiime/util.py", line 49, in <module>
    from skbio.util import remove_files, create_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skbio/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import skbio.io
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skbio/io/__init__.py", line 309, in <module>
    import_module('skbio.io.clustal')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skbio/io/clustal.py", line 123, in <module>
    from skbio.alignment import Alignment
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skbio/alignment/__init__.py", line 230, in <module>
    from ._alignment import Alignment, SequenceCollection, StockholmAlignment
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skbio/alignment/_alignment.py", line 21, in <module>
    from skbio.stats.distance import DistanceMatrix
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skbio/stats/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from ._subsample import subsample, subsample_counts, isubsample
ImportError: cannot import name subsample_counts
```

I have 
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-55-generic x86_64), qiime 1.9, python 2.7.6

any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not seeing the qiime folder in the $PATH or $PYTHONPATH. When I ran print_qiime_config.py I got this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/print_qiime_config.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise ImportError("%s\n%s" % (e, core_dependency_missing_msg))
ImportError: cannot import name subsample_counts

Comment: are you using the virtual machine qiime ? or Did you install qiime on your computer?

Comment: qiime is on an ubuntu server that I access from my mac (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-55-generic x86_64))

Comment: can you show inputs files the `assign_taxonomy.py` script for reply ? ..... I use qiime 1.9.1, may be a problem with the version 1.9

Comment: **reply** = backtracking = remake ..... ;)

Comment: I tried every single script with parameters, without parameters, even the test and i always get the same error

Comment: I ran the same in the EC2 and work...but I want to fix the one in the server. I think something went wrong with the instalation.